Restore EC2 backup in S3 to RDS using Percona xtra-backup
I have an EC2 (MYSQL instance) backup which is stored in S3 currently ,  I want that backup to be restored (using percona Xtra bakcup ) in an RDS database instance. Is it possible?
And what if the backup data is encrypted ? is it still possible ?
Here is the blog I referred to --> https://www.percona.com/blog/migrate-to-amazon-rds-with-percona-xtrabackup/
but this blog was written in 2018 , so i am not sure if it's still applicable. please help
